# Error al ejecutar script de python para eternal blue

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Estoy intentando hacer pentesting hacia un windows 7 Professional usando la vulnerabilidad eternal blue.
Estoy intentando correr este scrip (enlace web codigo raw de github):
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/worawit/MS17-010/master/zzz_exploit.py
Al intentar ejecutar el codigo me lanza errores. No es la primera vez que me saltan errores al ejecutar un script the python.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la sección `issues` de la página de github de ese software encontré esta pregunta: https://github.com/worawit/MS17-010/issues/48

Al parecer es una incompatibilidad con python3.

La respuesta que dieron fue utilizar este software en su lugar: https://github.com/3ndG4me/AutoBlue-MS17-010